# C# abstract base class - extending the implementation

Tags: c#, abstract, extend, radix

I have the following case:

```
   public class GeoLocation
   {
       public double Longitude { get; set; }
       public double Latitude { get; set; }
       public string LocationName { get; set; }
   }

    public abstract class Base
    {
        public abstract GeoLocation GeoLocation { get; set; }
    }

    public class Concrete : Base
    {
        public override GeoLocation GeoLocation
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

Now if I create a class `Concrete2` which inherits from `Base` as well and I want the `GeoLocation` object to have 1 more property:

```
public string Address{ get; set; }
```

What is the best way to implement this?

I could create a new class called `GeoLocationEx : GeoLocation` and place `Address` property there but then in my Concrete2 object, I would have 2 properties: `GeoLocation` and `GeoLocationEx` which I do not like...

I could also make the GeoLocation class partial and extend it with `Address` property for the `Concrete2` class but I am not sure would this be a "proper" use of partial classes.

What could be the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why do you want a descendant class to work with an extended `GeoLocation` object? In that case, if you wanted to work with `Concrete2` objects via `Base`'s interface, you would have to check if it's `Concrete2` object, not `Concrete`, and only then pass in the `GeoLocationEx` object.

Comment: Why can't you simply add "Address" to the GeoLocation object?

Comment: I found solution looking at this post:

abstract class Request<T> where T : Parameters {
  T Parameters;
}

class Specialized : Request<SpecialParameters> {
}

Comment: Some classes that inherit from base class have different properties than the other in this GeoLocation property...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use generics:

```
        public class GeoLocation
        {
            public double Longitude { get; set; }
            public double Latitude { get; set; }
            public string LocationName { get; set; }
        }

        public class GeoLocationEx : GeoLocation
        {
            public double Address { get; set; }
        }

        public abstract class Base<T>
        {
            public abstract T GeoLocation { get; set; }
        }

        public class Concrete : Base<GeoLocation>
        {
            public override GeoLocation GeoLocation
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }

        public class Concrete2 : Base<GeoLocationEx>
        {
            public override GeoLocationEx GeoLocation
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The problem with this is that Concrete and Concrete2 does not share the same base class.

Comment: I went for the generic solution...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class GeoLocation
{
    public GeoLocation(GeoLocation obj) {/* implement a copy constructor */}
    public GeoLocation() {/* default constructor */}

    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
}

public class GeoLocationEx : GeoLocation
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract GeoLocation GeoLocation { get; set; }
}

public class Concrete2 : Base
{
    private GeoLocationEx _geoLocation;
    public override GeoLocation GeoLocation
    {
        get { return _geoLocation; }
        set
        {
            _geoLocation = new GeoLocationEx(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Now inside the `Concrete2` class you can work directly with the private `GeoLocationEx` field. Also, you can expose additional public methods for `Concrete2`-specific stuff.

Refer to MSDN on writing copy constructors: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173116(v=vs.80).aspx